# Validação formulario

Tags: javascript, css

Crie a classe de estilo CSS denominada“invalido”, cuja formatação é ter a seguinte cor de fundo: #A00 e o texto de cor branca.  Altere  a  validação  de  formulário  de  forma  que,  caso  um  campo  de  formulário  esteja  inválido,  assuma  esta  classe.  Caso esteja correto, volte ao estilo padrão

```html
<div>
  <label for="txtNome">Nome:</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtNome" name="txtNome" size="50" maxlength="100">
  <p class="aviso" id="avisoTxtNome" style="display:none;">Este campo não pode ficar vazio!</p>
</div>
```

```js
if (document.getElementById("txtNome").value.length < 3) {
  alert('Por favor, preencha o campo nome');
  document.getElementById("txtNome").focus();
  return false
}
```

Ou seja altere o alert para o que está na no html, mas utilizando esses métodos citados.

Comment: Confuso... pode reformular?

Comment: sim, vou reformular :D

Comment: O modo como você descreveu sua pergunta me parece um exercicio acadêmico, estou correto?

Answer (score 0):

Altere o evento (`onkeyup`) conforme sua necessidade (`onblur`, `onfocus`, ...).

Execute o código abaixo e comece a digitar letra por letra para entender:

```js
var elementoValidar = document.getElementById('txtNome');

function valida() {
    if (elementoValidar.value.length < 3) {
     elementoValidar.className = "invalido";  
    } else {
        elementoValidar.className = "ok";  
    }
}
```

```css
input[type="text"].invalido {
  background-color : #a00; 
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"].ok {
  background-color : #0a0; 
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="txtNome">Nome:</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtNome" name="txtNome" onkeyup="valida()" size="50" maxlength="100" />
  <p class="aviso" id="avisoTxtNome" style="display:none;">Este campo não pode ficar vazio!</p>
</div>
```